# IPhone Developer Account в Украине

Tags: xcode, ios

Доброго времени суток всем. Я решил приобрести сертификат iOS разработчика и столкнулся со множеством проблем, вообще не понимаю, как я буду получать деньги с продаж, какую карту привязать к аккаунту, какие законы я нарушаю и все такое... Кто занимается разработкой в Украине - поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста, расскажите, как все сделать правильно.
Спасибо.

Comment: Ответьте еще на такой вопрос: я отправил заявку, деньги пока что не списали, написано: Developer Program Status: Enrollment Pending; я, читая обсуждение темы регистрации, прочитал про отправку факса, но меня не просили его отправлять и я ничего не отправлял, что мне делать, ждать?

Comment: Факс уже отправлять не нужно. Вам на почту должно прийти два сообщения. Первое, что заявка на регистрацию подана, а второе письмо уже прийдет, когда спишут деньги. В нем будет ссылка, по которой нужно будет перейти и активировать iPhone Developer Program.

Comment: О, понятно, спасибо большое

Comment: Я подал заявку 24 числа вечером, мне сразу де пришло письмо, что мой заказ принят, сумма 99$ и что заказ будет обработан в течение 2 business days, но еще ничего не пришло, это нормально?

Comment: Прошу прощения, но не могли бы вы дать мне свой логин Skype? А то я теперь пытаюсь опубликовать  приложение, но что-то мне ничего не понятно, а на форуме общаться именно с Вами не очень-то удобно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Привет!

Распишу подробнее как дело обстояло у меня. Я сходил в ближайшее отделение приват банка, узнал у сотрудника возможность получить валютную карту. Для регистрации в iOS Developer Program нужна именно **валютная** карта. Ждал я карту 10 дней. Ее делают "на заказ". На карте была фотография, имя держателя карты, срок действия, а также CVV код.

> Как зарегистрироваться?

Тут все стандартно. Получили нашу валютную карту, пополнили ее на 100$. Я просто перевел деньги с гривневой карты на валютную. При переводе UAH конвертируется в USD по текущему курсу. Далее идем на developer.apple.com и регистрируемся.

Регистрация в Apple Developer Program простой процесс. Там заполняем нужные поля: имя, фамилия, город и прочее. Внимательно проверяем номер карты, который ввели, а также **имя держателя карты**.

> Какую карту потом привязываем к учетной записи?

Привязываем нашу валютную карту, вводим имя держателя карты и МФО.

> Как я буду получать деньги с продаж?

Выплаты производятся ежемесячно, если сумма превышает 150$. Если к примеру пришла сумма 140$, то она автоматически переносится на следующий месяц. Когда деньги попадают на карту, приходит SMS.

> Какие законы я нарушаю?

Да вроде бы ничего не нарушаешь

Если остались вопросы - спрашивай :)

Comment: А что касательно налога? Есть ли он и, если да, то сколько процентов? Как его выплачивать?

Comment: А могут ли спросить, откуда эти деньги, каким путем я их получил?

Comment: Скажите еще такое: когда вы в последний раз снимали деньги с карты? А то в последнее время внимание к валютным поступлениям из-за границы повышенное, например, мои знакомые не могут снять деньги с валютной карты PayPal, а как у Вас?

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, если возникнут еще вопросы - напишу.